# Get the string-encoded key of an entity from a reference property in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, referenceproperty

In order to get the string-encoded key of an entity, I just do the following:

```
key = entity.key()
string_encoded_key = str(key)
```

I have a reference to another entity via the ReferenceProperty.

```
class ParentClass(db.Model):
name = db.StringProperty()

class ChildClass(db.Model):
name = db.StringProperty()
bio_parent = db.ReferenceProperty(ParentClass)


johnnys_parent = ParentClass(name="John").put()
child = ChildClass(name="Johnny",bio_parent=johnnys_parent).put()

#getting the string-encoded key of the parent through the child
child = ChildClass.all().filter("name","Johnny").get()
string_encoded_key = str(child.bio_parent) # <--- this doesn't give me the string-encoded key
```

How do I get the string-encoded key of the biological parent through the child entity without fetching the parent entity?

Thanks!

Comment: i think my answer will help you.. else try to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the key of a reference property without fetching it like this:

```
ChildClass.bio_parent.get_value_for_datastore(child_instance)
```

From there, you can fetch the string encoded form as you normally would.

Comment: I am starting to become a fan of yours. Can you provide me some good books for appengine

Comment: @Abdul That depends what sort of book you're looking for. Programming Google App Engine, by Dan Sanderson, is good.

Answer (score 1):

**[parent](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model)** is a keyword argument in the Model Class. So, when you use

```
child = Child (name='Johnny', parent=parent)
```

it refers to the **[parent](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model)** of that entity and not the **parent** attribute. You should change the name of the attribute from parent to something more meaningful and less ambiguous.

```
class ParentClass (db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty ()

class ChildClass (db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty ()
  ref = db.ReferenceProperty (ParentClass)

johns_parent = ParentClass (name='John Sr.').put ()
john = ChildClass (name='John Jr.', ref=johns_parent).put ()

# getting the string encoded key
children = ChildClass.all ().filter ('name', 'John Jr.').get ()
string_encoded_key = str (children.ref)
```

The parent of an entity can be assigned only at the time of creation. It is in the full key path of the entity and can not be changed in the entire life of that entity.

Resources :

1. [Model Class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model)
2. [Reference Property](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty)
3. [Entity Groups and Ancestor Path](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths)

Comment: Ok, I edited it accordingly. Do you have a suggestion on how I can get the string-encoded key of the biological parent of the child through the childclass entity without fetching the parentclass entity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve  this way.

```
string_encoded_key = str(child.bio_parent.key())
```

Comment: I wanted to get the string-encoded key *without* fetching the parentclass entity from the datastore. Your answer fetches it from the datastore first.

Comment: Yes, your solution works, but it doesn't fit the requirements. As I stated in my question, I wanted to get it WITHOUT FETCHING the parentclass entity from the datastore. Your solution fetches the parentclass, which I want to avoid.

Comment: I think it's not possible to do that .In that way, you can change your model to store the key using db.ListProperty(db.Key). To know more about modeling you can have a look here [Appengine Data modeling](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)